# Using htaccess, how do I set "www.mysite.com/page.php?get=myname" to "www.mysite.com/myname"?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a page "page.php" on my site "www.mysite.com". "page.php" is a profile page for users on my website. Users profile can be accessed like this: "http://www.mysite.com/page.php?user=rehan". Using htaccess, I would like to rewrite the link to: "http://www.mysite.com/rehan". How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Rehan.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)$ page.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to use :

`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^//]+)$ page.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]`
```

but on some servers you have to add :

```
RewriteBase /
```